# What are Query Params for the spreadsheet export endpoint in the Google Docs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-docs-api

I'm trying to export a Google Sheet spreadsheet to PDF with the Google Docs API endpoint `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/export`.

I found this endpoint in Google Apps Script samples: [Generate & send PDFs from Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/generate-pdfs) and the [sample](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1k9PjGdQ_G0HKEoS3np_Szfe-flmLw9gUvblQIxOfvTmS-NLeLgVUzvOa/edit) itself.

Here the function from the sample that contains the endpoint:

```js
function createPDF(ssId, sheet, pdfName) {
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=7&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=true&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');

  // Gets the folder in Drive where the PDFs are stored.
  const folder = getFolderByName_(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME);

  const pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
  return pdfFile;
}
```

The `url` from the above code block contains the endpoint.

---

I tried to find some documentation about endpoint query params in google documentations, but found nothing.

Then I found the gist on the GitHub: https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70. The developer, Spencer Easton, tells in the gist about query params, but didn't left any reference where they found this information or how they found this information.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @daimto, google has the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/generate-pdfs) on how to generate a pdf from a spreadsheet, so it can